# Tensorflow detection API SsdFeatureExtractor' object has no attribute 'override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams'

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, object-detection

When I use ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017 model to train myself data set,

I use google TensorFlow detection API to train that

There are some problems will arise.
my os: ubuntu 16.04

> **./train.sh**
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "../../train.py", line 167, in 
>       tf.app.run()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 126, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(argv))   File "../../train.py", line 163, in main
>       worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)   File "/home/feng/project/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line
>   240, in train
>       detection_model = create_model_fn()   File "/home/feng/project/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py",
>   line 98, in build
>       add_background_class)   File "/home/feng/project/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py",
>   line 166, in _build_ssd_model
>       is_training=is_training)   File "/home/feng/project/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py",
>   line 129, in _build_ssd_feature_extractor
>   feature_extractor_config.override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams)
>
> ***AttributeError: 'SsdFeatureExtractor' object has no attribute 'override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams'***

**What kind of question is that?**

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend you check out the below issue reported on the TensorFlow Object Detection API Git:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4121

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently after upgrading my TensorFlow Object Detection API and fixed it by refreshing the protobuf bindings.

This kind of error message can happen why you have the wrong protobuf bindings installed, since the new bindings may be incompatible with the old version bindings that are still being referenced. You can fix this by downloading the newest version of protobuf and compiling the new bindings.

To do this follow the instructions for "Manual protobuf-compiler installation and usage" found here: [Section Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#manual-protobuf-compiler-installation-and-usage), but to future proof this against a future broken link, I will note that they currently instruct you to:

1. Make `tensorflow/models/research` the current directory
2. Download and install the latest version of `protoc` (aka protobuf)

   - `wget -O protobuf.ziP`
   - `https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0/protoc-3.0.0-linux-x86_64.zip`
   - `unzip protobuf.zip`
3. Run the compilation process **with the downloaded version** (the old version may still be in your path and you might need it elsewhere).

   - `./bin/protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`
4. Add libraies to `PYTHONPATH`

   - `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:` `` `pwd` `` `:` `` `pwd` `` `/slim`
5. Test the installation

   - `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`